# Is there any way to transform query data and map according to that type in react-query v4?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I am trying to transform query data from API response. More specifically I want to add two additional property. That is why I use `select` configuration in `useQuery` hook like this:
[image]
But in this case I didn't get suggestion for extra two properties. That's why I've add another model and use it with `useQuery` hook like this:
[image]
But it troughing error.

I am stucked with this.

edit on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-example-38gmvp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, the probblem is that the first generic type parameter of `useQuery` is not the returned data type. It's the `queryFn` return type. You can put the `ModifiedProduct[]` to the third generic type parameter or that the code infer itself.

```
  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["fetch-products"],
    queryFn: fetchProducts,
    select: (data) => {
      const items = data.map(
        (prod): ModifiedProduct => ({
          ...prod,
          dateOfAdd: new Date(),
          dateOfUpdate: new Date()
        })
      );
      return items;
    }
  });

// this should also work
  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery<Product[], unknown, ModifiedProduct[]>({
    queryKey: ["fetch-products"],
    queryFn: fetchProducts,
    select: (data) => {
      const items = data.map(
        (prod): ModifiedProduct => ({
          ...prod,
          dateOfAdd: new Date(),
          dateOfUpdate: new Date()
        })
      );
      return items;
    }
  });
```

Comment: appreciated your help.
One more q is, can I use a string array (sring[]) as a third parameter if select configuration return title like this: `data.map(prod=>prod.title)`.
In this case, useQuery fires error.

Comment: please see this section on type inference in the docs. You shouldn't need to add generics to useQuery. Use the first suggestion of this answer. https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/typescript#type-inference